# filter each line of linux bash output by regexp

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to filter the output of arbitrary output e.g. `cat` or `objdump` to only display lines which contain "pattern".

Is there a one-liner UNIX/Linux command to do this?

e.g. `cat filepath | xargs grep 'pattern' -l` is not working for me

Comment: `xargs` would pass each line of the output as an independent argument to `grep`. `grep` is very much capable of reading from `stdin` when you pipe the output of `cat`. So merely removing `xargs` should work. The `-l` option to grep is not really required for your use case. And if you do use `-l` it should be before the pattern and not after ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
cat file | grep pattern
```

You could also just use `grep pattern file` if it's a static file.

Comment: you can use the ``-n`` flag to display line numbers. ``cat file | grep -n pattern``

Comment: ah so simple...answer accepted!

Answer (score 18):

Better to use `grep -e` or `egrep`(this allows for extended regular expressions).
Then you can do more robust things with regex:

```
 cat my_phonebook | egrep "[0-9]{10}"
```

To show all 10 digit phone numbers in a file.

If you toss in a `-o`, only the numbers get returned (instead of the before and after content on the line).